# Firebase legacy email template

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've migrated my existing firebase to the new console. Everything looks OK except that it's still using the legacy email template for password reset. For some reason, it won't let me use the new template. Is there a way to delete the legacy email template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Dumpee you have to use the new SDK to switch to the new templates. So if you are building a web app, you have to include Firebase 3.1 src code and call the relevant API to reset password.

Comment: I see. Not ready to switch yet but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks bojeil.

Answer (score 1):

Even after migrating your Firebase project to the new console the [2.x SDKs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/) will still continue to use the legacy email template when issuing password resets.  If you use the [3.x SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/) and issue a password reset from there it will use the new email template.

In either case you can manually trigger a password reset email that uses the new email template by going to the users tab in the authentication section (found at `console.firebase.google.com/project/<your project name>/authentication/users`) through the menu button on the right side of the user's row.  Or you can change the wording of either the legacy or the new reset password email in the email templates tab in the auth section.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply.